# How do I relink or open a project in Mapbox Studio after changing the path?

Tags: mapbox

I changed some folder names and lost the ability to open my projects in Mapbox Studio. Changing the folder names back did not help. How do you open or link a project to Mapbox Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look on your computer for your .tm2 files that is how Mapbox Studio saves projects.

Once you have located the .tm2 files open Mapbox Studio and locate the Projects icon in the bottom left of the program. 
[image]

from there click "Browse" and navigate to your .tm2 file and select "Open"

[image]

Comment: Oh goodness thank you. I think if the button said "Open" I would have realized that. I lost hours recreating files I could not open for a demo.